# To insert a user info to another wp site using $wpdb

Tags: database, wordpress

I want to insert a user from another wordpress site. I used the bellow code for this. But i got a error.

```
Call to a member function query() on a non-object
```

My code for insert the user table

```
    global $mydb;
    $mydb = new wpdb(My DB information here...);
    $rows = $mydb->get_results("select user_nicename from wp_users");
    $sql = "INSERT INTO wp_users (user_login,user_pass,user_pass,user_nicename,user_email,user_url,display_name) 
        VALUES ('$fields[username]','$fields[password]','$fields[user_nicename]','$fields[user_email]','$fields[wpmem_reg_url]','$fields[wpmem_reg_url]','$fields[display_name]')";
  $wpdb->query($sql);
```

Why cant i insert the data and get the error. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring `$mydb` as global connection object and executing query with `$wpdb`
change it to

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO wp_users (user_login,user_pass,user_nicename,user_email,user_url,display_name) 
        VALUES ('$fields[username]','$fields[password]','$fields[user_nicename]','$fields[user_email]','$fields[wpmem_reg_url]','$fields[display_name]')";
  $mydb->query($sql);
```

Comment: Yes i have written the same in the last line. $mydb->query($sql); But still no tgetting the error.

Comment: Sorry for double writting. But can you write the changes with the whole code, So that i can understand what you want to point here.